# How Can I Return Exit Code To Variable On Local Computer From Script Run On Remote Computer?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am attempting to execute a Powershell script on a remote computer from a Powershell window on my local computer using Powershell 2.0.  My goal is to store an exit code from the script on the remote computer to a variable on my local computer, whether it be in a local script or just a local Powershell window.  Currently all I get back is an error message stating the following . . .

```
Cannot invoke pipeline because run space is not in the Opened state. Current state of run space is Closed. + CategoryInfo: OperationStopped: Microsoft.Power...tHelperRunspace:ExecutionCmdletHelperRunspace) [], InvalidRunspaceStateException + FullyQualifiedErrorID : RemotePipeLineExecutionFailed
```

My situation is this . . . I am trying to return an exit code to a variable on my local machine from a script on a remote machine. There are actually two scripts involved here and both are on the remote machine and in the same folder. The first script is called "VerifyBatchExistence.ps1". This file takes as input a batch file called "Batch.ps1", an integer that represents an exit code to be output if "Batch.ps1" does not exist, another integer representing the number of parameters needed by "Batch.ps1", and the variable string(s) needed as input for "Batch.ps1". Within "Batch.ps1" I have the following piece of code which I expect to be triggered when one of my passed-in parameters is invalid. . .

```
exit 931
```

Within "VerifyBatchExistence.ps1" I have the following piece of code . . .

```
Powershell - File .\Batch.ps1 BATCHPARAM1 BATCHPARAM2

$Code1 = $LASTEXITCODE

$Host.SetShouldExit($Code1)

exit
```

On my local machine, I did the following . . .

```
$Remote=New-PSSession -ComputerName 7.7.7.7 -Credential $cred

Invoke-Command -Session $Remote -ScriptBlock {$Code1=.\VerifyBatchExistence.ps1 7777 2 .\Batch.ps1 NAME1 NAME2}

$Code2=Invoke-Command -Session $Remote -ScriptBlock {$Code1}
$Code2
```

After this, I receive the error stated above. Any idea what I am doing wrong or how I can return an exit code to a variable on my local machine from a remote machine which has a script consuming and running a second script? Any answer to this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
invoke-command -session $Remote -scriptblock { mycommand }
$remotelastexitcode = invoke-command -session $Remote -ScriptBlock { $lastexitcode }

if ( $remotelastexitcode -ne 0 )
{
    "$remotelastexitcode"
    exit 1
}
```